# Expecting Json output Format is Like [ { },{ } ]

Tags: php, ios, json

I'm using Json to retrieve the info by webServices. I got a file on PHP to achieve it but the O/P format is different .

```
$sql=mysql_query("select phone1 from xxx where id='".$amp."'");

$response = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
//    print_r($row);
    $sql_query=mysql_query("select x,y,z from tblRepairQueue where phoneNo='".$row['phone1']."'");
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)){

        $ackNo=$row1['ackNo'];
        $repairStatus=$row1['repairStatus'];
        $savedAt=$row1['savedAt'];

        $response[]=array("ackNo"=>"$ackNo","repairStatus"=>"$repairStatus","savedAt"=>"$savedAt");
    }}
print json_encode($response);
```

Actually I'm using this on IOS to decode using

```
    NSMutableDictionary *userDetails = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
   options:0 error:nil];
```

The O/p which I'm getting for

> NSLog(@"%@", userDetails);

```
(
        {
        ackNo = "21031221201377 ";
        repairStatus = "Closed and Complete";
        savedAt = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    }
)
```

> I'm expecting is like `[{}, {}]`

```
 [
            {
            ackNo = "21031221201377 ";
            repairStatus = "Closed and Complete";
            savedAt = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        }
    ]
```

How to achieve it , I don't know much about PHP . So grateful if anyone's of suggestion .

Comment: What you want ? Why you need [] instead of () ?

Comment: b'coz I need to use in IOS as Array for multiple Records.

Comment: NSString *key = [keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [userDetails objectForKey:key]; .. I'm getting the error for this st.

Comment: Error : [__NSCFArray allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa79fa90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS `()` refers to Arrays and `{}` refers to dictionary.
So you are getting the correct response.

You need to change your code like:

```
NSMutableArray *userDetails = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
   options:0 error:nil];
```

And access the data like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *user = [userDetails objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"ackNo : %@",[user objectForKey:@"ackNo"]);
```

Comment: I'm getting the compile time error For **NSMutableDictionary *user = [userDetails objectAtIndex:0];** Is No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex'

Comment: @KumarKl: did you changed the `NSMutableDictionary *userDetails` to `NSMutableArray *userDetails` ? Please check the answer, I changed that part also and it is working for me.

Comment: I changed Again : Error:[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @KumarKl: are you using the above code, I don't think so. I used exactly the same code and it works. I think you wrote like: `NSLog(@"ackNo : %@",[userDetails objectForKey:@"ackNo"]);` instead of `NSLog(@"ackNo : %@",[user objectForKey:@"ackNo"]);`

Comment: @KumarKl: it's ok dude :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct response. The only thing I would change is remove the quotes in your variables when you are creating the response array.

```
$response[]=array("ackNo"=>$ackNo,"repairStatus"=>$repairStatus,"savedAt"=>$savedAt);
```

Its a personal choice, but I think is more readable that way.